# Daily vote count effect on review Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Whilst reviewing, this popped up: ( just took a screen shot of the important parts)
[image]

I think Understand this, if you have hit your vote count for the day it is only "first posts" and "late answers" categories wherein you could possibly up/down vote the question/answer.

But this is only part of what you can do, you can add comments, accept the "first posts" {which don't count towards your daily limit} etc. etc.

The system currently determines the ability to vote against a limit on a case by case basis.  This code should be brought to bear if a person decides to vote whilst inside these categories, rather than limiting access to the categories in general.

Of course I may be totally mis-interpreting this.